# How to make the image overlap the nav-pills?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to make the image overlap the navbar(nav-pills) below it?
Here it the link to fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/arpittomar/5Ledeorr/

To summarize:

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="overlap">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" class="img-thumbnail">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="internal_navbar">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
          <li><a href="#">Timeline</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here i want to make the image overlap the ul elements below it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: absolute` for the `<ul>` and the `<img>` and `z-index: 1` for the `<img>`:

```
.nav-pills, .img-thumbnail {
  position: absolute;
}

.img-thumbnail {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Ledeorr/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use absolute position for the image tag and whichever component you want on top just add z-index:1 to it

```
.img-thumbnail{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
}
```

I think this wil work for you for demo check http://jsfiddle.net/5Ledeorr/5/